# Wearing orthotics in lifting shoes

Tags: shoes, olympic-weightlifting

I am planning to start taking Olympic lifting classes. Since I want to take it seriously, I wanted to makes sure I am geared properly. Currently, I am using orthotics due to the leg length discrepancy (longer left leg) and flat feet which is combined with hyper-mobile feet.

Because of the collapsing of my arches on my feet, my feet have naturally gotten wider than average and it is sometimes a pain to find proper shoes also. I would love to do all my power lifts bare-feet but experience shows me that it is best to do it with orthotic intervention. So I need some sort of vessel to house the correction insoles and make sure there is no intra-foot movement, because I once tried dead-lift only with the soles, and that turned into a fiasco due to lack of traction... even Steve Wonder saw that coming!

The gear I currently use are:
- Chuck taylors for powerlifting excersizes
- Asic Gel Nimbus 15 for running
- Adidas Supernova Glide for running, walking with anti-pronation support for walking
- Adidas Samba classics from the 90's with a tough rubber sole for when I need a change of gear.

I have a couple of questions regarding this. I hope you folks can help me.

- Which brands do you use? (I was thinking of Adidas Adipower or Adidas power perfect 2)
- What type of materials should I ask my podiatrist to use in case new insoles need to be cast
- What else can I do or use to make sure that learning Olympic lifts will be more fun than rather concentrating on corrections and deficits all the time?

Thanks a big bunch!

Comment: Wow! You seem to have a lot of shoes for working out. Isn't that a big pain to remember what to wear for what exercise? :)

Comment: I have a habit of checking out what really works out for me and checking specs is what I do ifirst on when I am into something. It also eases my mind to have an appropriate gear for a given target which in the long term makes sure that moneywise I get the best out of the equipment. for the remebering part: It might sound autistic but I prepare my gear in the evening before and since I know what I am doing the next day, the right shoe for the day goes in the dufflebag and gets out while preparing for the next.

Comment: So, what happens if you need to perform more than one exercise? Maybe walking after a run *(as that's common during runs)* . You aren't gonna stop to change your shoes, are you? :)

Comment: To be honest, I change them if it is necessary, but usually I bench with running shoes and then do 400m sprints afterwards. And I have s speicific GPP day where I take multiple pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for those who have wide feet when it comes to oly lifting shoes. Nike Romaleos 2 (interchangeable soles in the shoes which is a big +) and Adidas power perfect 2.

I find adidas power perfect 2 pretty affordable and had to rip the glued soles out of the shoes. Orthotics fit perfectly and my toes can move.

For the material of the insoles, my podiatrist is waiting for the new material which is being tested by her vendors.